# How to quickly request for restoring object in deep glacier in s3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have more than 300,000 objects in a bucket.

They are under the deep glacier and I would like to restore objects for analysis.

When I tried to benchmark the speed of the `restore api`, it seems to be slow for me to process all these objects.

Below is my python code.

```
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects')
operation_parameters = {'Bucket': bucket,
                        'Prefix': prefix}

page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters)

cnt = 0
for page in page_iterator:
    for content in page['Contents']:
        try:
            print(content['Key'])
            s3.restore_object(
                Bucket=bucket,
                Key=content['Key'],
                RestoreRequest={
                    'Days': 1,
                    'GlacierJobParameters': {
                        'Tier': 'Standard',
                    },
                },
            )
        except:
             print("already restored..")
```

I found that batch operation is focused on speeding up for this scenario but I don't want to use the aws console.

Rather than using the aws console as GUI interface, I want to code it using python as code above.

Is there more efficient way to restore large objects in python boto? (Not using big data tools such as spark)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice is either loop through the objects and call `restore_object()` for each of them, or use **S3 Batch Operations** to 'bulk restore' them.

Anything you can do in the console can also be done through code.

To create an S3 Batch Operations job, use [`create_job()` - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3control/client/create_job.html).

If you wish to use your existing code, you could make it run faster by calling `restore_object()` in parallel (eg using `asyncio`) without waiting for a response, but this requires some advanced Python skills.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I use the `asyncio` then, the results will be always same for the case when I use it without `asyncio`. I mean that there will be no possibility to lose the request?

Comment: There is a possibility of network failures, so the code should wait for a response to be sure it was received correctly. I was trying to say that it can keep sending `restore_object()` requests in parallel, without having to wait for the earlier request to receive a response before sending the next request.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response. I understand what you mean. Last one more thing. If the network failures happens, the client side requests again in automatic way or I should write some codes to retry it?

Comment: If an error is returned, then your code be responsible for trying again.